# html5 editor using webkit

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an html5 editor using webkit in C# WinForms. If this is possible, can anyone suggest some resources or links? If webkit is not suitable for creating an html5 editor, is there an alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate webkit into web forms with [1].  I'd use something like FCKEditor plugged into it.

However, all that is a little bloated considering the use case.  I'd prefer to use something native rather than piggyback the entire of webkit on top of web forms.  You could use an embedded IE instance easier with an editor in that without having to ship webkit as a dependency.  There is something at [2] which is possible as native winforms but I've not tried it.

1. http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/
2. http://windowsclient.net/articles/htmleditor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

flowing link may helpful for you.

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5.ars